# Is it right to say 'You don't ever learn to fly if you won't try'

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it right to say in poem

> 'You don't ever learn to fly if you won't try'

Is it right to use 'don't ever' here or is the construction wrong?

Comment: No, it should be "You *won't* ever learn to fly if you *don't* try."

Comment: P.S. This is not *subjunctive*, Tanya, this is a *[conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence)*, with a protasis (the "if-part") and an apodosis (the "then-part"). For a rough description, you might google "First, Second, and Third Conditional".

Comment: It isn't the way we would generally talk most of the time. But in the end I don't think it's really so objectionable, and for a poem it's less so.

Answer (score 4):

It's the other way round. You don't use the if-clause in the future. In this sentence the if-clause should be in the present with the main clause in the future. As commented by user3169, the correct sentence is:

You won't ever learn to fly if you don't try.